# Debug Windows Phone 7 application that contacts locally hosted WCF server

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-7, local

I've built a WP7 application and a locally hosted (on my machine) WCF server in my solution. I have debugged it using the emulator and it works fine, however, when I debug via device and try to connect to the server I get an exception stating that the EndPointNotFound (I'm aware I haven't set up anything to catch this exception!). Is there anyway to connect to a localhost server via the device?

Many thanks

Jonno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download and install the Visual Studio SP1 tooling and host your WCF services using IIS Express. This webserver accepts incoming connections from other computers on your local network as long as there's a firewall exception to allow the connection.

You'll have to connect to the machine hosting the service through it's external IP. That cannot be localhost or 127.0.0.1 (it has to be something belonging to the same subnet).

Scott Hanselman had a presentation about the "[MS Web Stack of Love](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX11/FRM02)" where he demos how to set all this up (using HTTPS even) and it goes into depth about how to configure the firewall and all that jazz. I recommend watching it, as he is also, a funny guy.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to connect to your local machine from an actual device and it si not tethered, make sure that you are connected to the same local network.

What is the host name you are using to try and connect to the host machine? The emualtor will be able to resolve "localhost" to the host mahcien but your phone won't. You'll need to use the appropriate host name or IP address.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Wifi connection on WP7 and the local ip of your server in the config file to reference your WCF server ?